# What is the simplest code for BST (Binary Search Tree) in Python with remove(key) method

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

```
class bst:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        
def insert(root, key):
    if not root:
        return bst(key)
    if key >= root.value:
        root.right = insert(root.right, key)
    elif key < root.value:
        root.left = insert(root.left, key)
    return root
        
def search(root, key):
    while root:
        if key == root.value:
            return True
        elif key >= root.value:
            root = root.right 
        elif key < root.value:
            root = root.left
    return False

def inorder(root):
    if root:
        inorder(root.left)
        print(root.value)
        inorder(root.right)
```

Here i'm trying to remove a key, by setting the node to be deleted equal to None. But inorder() method prints it(None) too.

```
def inorder_successor(root): # minimum in right subtree
    successor = root
    while(root.left):
        root = root.left
        successor = root
    return successor

def remove(root, key):
    while root:
        print("root",root.value)
        if key > root.value:
            root = root.right 
        elif key < root.value:
            root = root.left
        else: # if key is equal to node
            if root.left and root.right:
                successor = inorder_successor(root.right)
                print("successor found ", successor.value)
                root.value = successor.value
                successor.value = None
                break
            elif root.right:
                root = root.right
                root.right.value = None
                root.right = None
            elif root.left:
                root = root.left
                root.left.value = None
                root.left = None
            else:
                root.value = None 
                root = None
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgEt6.png)

I'm trying to write the simplest possible code for BST.
Can your provide a simple implementation of remove(key) method?

Also point out if you see any mistake in this one. Thankyou!

Comment: You should start with writing *an* implementation before looking for the *best* one.

Comment: Hi Scott! i have given in the question.

Comment: I see an `insert`, a `search` and an `inorder`; no `remove`.

Comment: @ScottHunter now I have added 'remove' too

Comment: Your `insert` returns the new `root` that results from the tree modification.  Your `remove` should do the same; setting a local variable called `root` doesn't have any impact after the function returns.  Just adding `return root` to the end and making sure the caller assigns the result to `root` (or `tree` or whatever) in its own scope might do the trick.

Comment: @Samwise `insert` method is recursive so it returns the root correctly from memory stack but `remove` is iterative. Also i have tested, remove() doesn't affect the root variable in main

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem.  If you `remove` the root node, and the caller's `root` variable doesn't change, obviously you didn't actually remove anything.  It doesn't matter if it's recursive or iterative, a local variable isn't visible to the caller if you don't `return` it.

Comment: I'm not removing the root node, i'm updating its value by the value of minimum in right subtree, the node which has to be deleted.

Comment: let me try by returning the root node.

Comment: @Samwise check the picture in output. tree is getting updated after remove() so returning root is not the problem

Comment: oh, I see, you're trying to modify the tree by resetting all the values.  Yikes!  Yeah, there's a much simpler way to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `None` to a node's value does not remove it. You should detach it from its parent, so that the parent's `left` or `right` attribute (which ever references the node to be removed) is set to `None`.

It is also misleading to call `inorder_successor` like that, because you pass it the root of the subtree, and are likely to return a node at the *left* of that root, so it is not the successor of the argument, but of some parent node that this function has no knowledge about.

I would suggest turning that function into `remove_successor`, so that it actually removes the intended node and returns the value of that removed node.

I would also make `remove` recursive, and let it *return* the new root (as the root itself could be removed, and so you'd have a new root afterwards).

Here is a possible correction to these two functions:

```
def remove_successor(root):
    successor = root.right
    if not successor.left:
        value = successor.value
        root.right = successor.right
        return value
    while successor.left:
        root = successor
        successor = successor.left
    value = successor.value
    root.left = successor.right
    return value

def remove(root, key):
    if not root:
        return
    if key > root.value:
        root.right = remove(root.right, key)
    elif key < root.value:
        root.left = remove(root.left, key)
    else: # if key is equal to node
        if root.left and root.right:
            root.value = remove_successor(root)
            print("successor found ", root.value)
        else:
            return root.right or root.left
    return root
```

When you call `remove`, make sure to capture the return value and re-assign it to the root. Example call:

```
root = None
for value in (8, 4, 12, 2, 6, 10, 14):
    root = insert(root, value)

inorder(root)
print("------")

root = remove(root, 8)
inorder(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive approach you used for `insert` is a good one, and it makes sense to use the same approach here:

```
from typing import Optional


def min_node(root: bst) -> bst:
    """Return the minimum (leftmost) node in this tree."""
    while root.left:
        root = root.left
    return root


def remove(root: bst, key: int) -> Optional[bst]:
    """Remove the given key from the tree, returning the new root."""
    # If the node to remove is in a child, ask the child tree
    # to remove the node, and re-assign the child tree 
    # if its root has changed.
    if root.value > key:
        root.left = remove(root.left, key)
        return root
    if root.value < key:
        root.right = remove(root.right, key)
        return root

    # Otherwise, this root is the one to remove.
    if root.left and root.right:
        # Stick the left tree under the min of the right tree.
        # The right tree is now the new root.
        min_node(root.right).left = root.left
        return root.right

    # Otherwise, whatever child exists is the new root.
    return root.left or root.right  # could be None!
```

Here's some code to test it out:

```
def print_tree(root: bst, level=0) -> None:
    if root.right:
        print_tree(root.right, level+1)
    print(f"{' '*level*4}{root.value}")
    if root.left:
        print_tree(root.left, level+1)


tree = None
nodes = [10, 5, 15, 2, 5, 13, 22, 12, 14]
for node in nodes:
    tree = insert(tree, node)

print("Full tree:")
print_tree(tree)

for node in nodes:
    print(f"Removing {node}...")
    tree = remove(tree, node)
    print_tree(tree) if tree else print("All gone!")
```

```
Full tree:
        22
    15
            14
        13
            12
10
        5
    5
        2
Removing 10...
    22
15
        14
    13
        12
                5
            5
                2
Removing 5...
    22
15
        14
    13
        12
            5
                2
Removing 15...
22
        14
    13
        12
            5
                2
Removing 2...
22
        14
    13
        12
            5
Removing 5...
22
        14
    13
        12
Removing 13...
22
    14
        12
Removing 22...
14
    12
Removing 12...
14
Removing 14...
All gone!
```